# Cloud Firestore request from Postman

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, postman, firebase-security

I have created a Cloud Firestore database, with a collection and some documents. I want to make some requests to it with Postman, but I am not able to authenticate. I have created a service credentials and tried to get the token for the authentication, with no success. Any idea about how to get it?

Which is the endpoint to get the token?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you've written that isn't working the way you expect.  We can't see from what you have here where you might be going wrong.

Comment: How are you making this requests? Did you write any http function to retrieve data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to use [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) you can obtain token with the following steps:

1. [Create a key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) for service account that you configured to access Firestore.
2. Open Cloud Shell, copy json with key info into it, and activate service account with `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<path_to_json>`
3. Print and copy its access token with `gcloud auth print-access-token`
4. Add `Authorization` header with value `Bearer <copied_token>` to your request or add it as a request parameter to url with `?access_token=<copied_token>`

Keep in mind that these tokens are short-lived and are valid maximum for an hour.